# Vue subfolder router

Tags: vue.js, router

I'm trying to deploy vue SPA (Vue2.5) in a subfolder, '/' route work correctly but others like '/login' return 404 error

**vue.config.ts**

```
publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
  ? './'
  : process.env.BASE_URL,
```

**index.ts (router)**

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes,
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  mode: 'history'
})
```

**.env**

```
BASE_URL=/subfolder/
```

Comment: How they can return 404 ? Vue router works client-side only.

Comment: How do you link to routes? So not `href="/login"`, but `:to="{ name: 'login' }"` or `:to="{ path: '/login' }"`? We have a `path: "*"` in our application to create a 404 in the app. Maybe this tripped you up? Can you show the URL for both cases (without the domain part, of course)?

Comment: If you want help, add more details about what are you doing before getting 404 response from the server (for example "I'm clicking on router link" or "im trying XXX url in the browser URL bar") + what is exactly the request send + what is your server (Express + node, Apache or some public hosting)